# 555 timer monostable time constants

Tags: 555, frequency-measurement

When making an monostable circuit with a 555 timber, the time that pin 3 is on is calculated using this:

*time on = 1.1 x R1 x C1*

My question is *why* is 1.1 included.

Comment: This is **NOT** a duplicate question. The other question is about *astable* operation; this one is about *monostable* operation.

Comment: Even mods make mistakes from time to time. It should be fine now.

Comment: Upvoted as a peace offering. Welcome to the site, @Coder101 :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monostable turns OFF when voltage on capacitor reaches 2/3 of VCC. 1.1×R1×C1 is time required for capacitor to charge to 2/3 VCC.

Comment: Will do a -1 - please explain in further depth

Comment: 1 time constant (RxC) will charge capacitor to roughly 63.2% of voltage applied. 1.1 time constant (1.1xRxC) will charge capacitor to about 66.6% (or 2/3rd) of voltage.

Comment: The (more) precise value is -ln(1/3) = 1.0986